# Cocoapods use another pod just in private pod, but not in projects using private pod

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to use another pod (SwiftyJSON) in a pod I'm creating, **without** making SwiftyJSON also available to projects that use my pod. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the .podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

    ...

    s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON'

    ...
end
```

And the podfile:

```
target '<my pod>' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

This works fine, except SwiftyJSON is now available to use as well on any project that uses my pod. How can I use SwiftyJSON **only** in my pod, without making SwiftyJSON available in other projects that use my pod?